# Частица не: слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

"Мы с ним незнакомы".

Comment: *"Не"* с *"знакомы"* пишется раздельно, так как у *"знакомы"* есть зависимые слова *"с ним"*.

Answer (score 4):

Тут действительно "возможны варианты". "Не()знакомы" может быть отдельным качеством (состоянием), может быть отрицанием "знакомы". К сожалению, различить бывает довольно сложно, наличие или отсутвие зависимых слов - признак мощный, но не абсолютный, к тому же само это понятие (зависимые слова) может быть различно истолковано.

Короче, в данном случае я бы предпочел слитное написние. "Мы с ним незнакомы". Конечно, если предложение дано полностью - и по условииям контенкста предполагается нейтральный стиль.

Answer (score 3):

На раздельное написание частицы НЕ влияет зависимое слово в том случае, когда речь идет о причастии. В данном предложении "знакомы" не причастие, а краткое прилагательное. Поэтому здесь частица НЕ пишется слитно.
   Единственное объяснение для возможного в данном случае раздельного написания дает Розенталь. Частица НЕ пишется слитно при утверждении, а раздельно - при отрицании. "Мы с ним незнакомы"(содержится утверждение, что мы чужие с ним) "Мы с ним не знакомы" (содержится отрицание того, что мы с ним знакомы)

Comment: Согласна с Вами. Я бы выбрала раздельное написание. Вообще наблюдается тенденция написания кратких прилагательных с НЕ раздельно.

Comment: Тенденция есть, но в нашем случае встречаются оба врианта, да и судя по нацкорпусу среди "тенденциозных" не так уж много авторитетных. Я не беру случаи, в которых слитное написание просто невозможно. 
Согласился бы с раздельным написанием, не будь "незнакомец", "незнакомка".  Это предполагает именно наличие качества "незнакомство".

Answer (score 2):

Слитное написание, так  как это краткое прилагательное. На него переносятся те же правила, что и для полного. Но, возможно, и раздельное. в случае, описанном Розенталем.

Answer (score 1):

Формально верны оба варианта, но только формально.  При решении таких задач лучше пользоваться не классическими (очень ограниченными в своих возможностях) правилами, а словарями.

Знакомый (человек) - состоящий в знакомстве, лично известный → незнакомый (человек) – не состоящий в знакомстве, не известный лично. (Слово чужой имеет другое значение: не родной, не из своей  семьи,  посторонний). Слитное или раздельное написание (незнакомый – не знакомый) не меняет смысл сказанного, поэтому желательно писать слитно, а раздельную форму написания применять только в отрицательных конструкциях, например: Мы не знакомы, но много слышали друг о друге.

ОТВЕТ 2.Мы с ним знакомы (состоим в знакомстве) - мы с ним не знакомы (не состоим в знакомстве)- мы с ним незнакомы (не состоим в знакомстве). Мне кажется, что варианты очень похожи по смыслу.
Еще проверка: мы незнакомы - мы были незнакомы, мы не знакомы - мы не были знакомы. Какая разница: мы были незнакомы и мы не были знакомы?

ПОПУТНЫЙ ПРИМЕР.
Когда мы сравниваем: не большой (средний) и небольшой (почти маленький), то между этими признаками существенная разница (она связана  с  так называемой градацией признака). Формально мы должны различать варианты: "город небольшой" и "город не большой", однако это чисто учебные примеры, так как в реальной жизни так никто не говорит. Если вы услышите "Город небольшой", то вы будете считать его маленьким, в противном случае лучше выразиться яснее, например: город не из больших. Это означает, что подобное сообщение мы воспринимаем как утвердительное, а для отрицания нужны дополнительные признаки.

И ЕЩЕ ОДНА ДЕТАЛЬ.В классических правилах обычно используются выражения "НЕ пишется раздельно или пишется слитно", и все это соотносится с десятками частных признаков. Мы решаем свою конкретную задачу, ищем подходящий вариант, и вся эта ФОРМАЛИСТИКА уже отодвигает смысл сообщения далеко в сторону, а о грамматике вообще некогда вспомнить. (А ведь задача выбора формы написания НЕ не только орфографическая, но и синтаксическая, потому что в действительности мы должны различить два вида предложений - утвердительное и отрицательное). Поэтому предлагается: считать по умолчанию все предложения утвердительными, а отрицательные конструкции применять по особому разрешению (здесь смайлик).

Comment: >Слитное или раздельное написание (незнакомый – не знакомый) не меняет смысл сказанного, поэтому желательно писать слитно  
  
Откуда такое неожиданное обоснование?  
Т.е. с идеей писать слитно в данном случае я согласен, но вот аргументация Ваша вызывает вопросы. 
Я так думаю, что скорее наоборот. ***Именно потому, что смысл утверждения несколько меняется*** от выбора слитного или раздельного написания, имеет смысл выбрать нужный.